# Why is JSON payload for int-http:outbound-gateway give 400 Bad Request?

Tags: json, rest, http, jackson, spring-integration

Why is JSON payload for int-http:outbound-gateway give 400 Bad Request?

Below request works fine on Chrome Rest Client with 3 headers specified in `inObjgateway` and JSON value of `Obj`

```
public class Obj {
    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String phoneNo;
    @JsonProperty("orderNumber")
    private String orderNmb;
}
```

Application Context Code Snippet is

```
<int:gateway id="inObjGateway" service-interface="com.XXX.xx.IObjGateway"
                 default-request-channel="smsHttpRequestChannel" default-reply-timeout="10000">
        <int:default-header name="content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <int:default-header name="authorization" value="someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome"/>
        <int:default-header name="accept" value="application/json" />
    </int:gateway>

    <int:payload-type-router input-channel="httpRequestChannel">
        <int:mapping type="com.xxx.xx.json.entity.Obj" channel="httpObjToJsonChannel"/>
    </int:payload-type-router>


    <int:channel id="httpRequestChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="httpOutChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="httpObjToJsonChannel"/>

    <int:object-to-json-transformer auto-startup="true" 
                                id="objectToJsonTxr" input-channel="httpObjToJsonChannel"
                                output-channel="smsHttpOutChannel"/>

    <bean id="httpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connectionTimeout}"/>
        <property name="readTimeout" value="${connectionTimeout}"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jackson2http" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="httpOutChannel" encode-uri="false"
                               url="http://www.someurl.com/something"
                               http-method="POST" auto-startup="true" request-factory="httpRequestFactory" 
                               reply-channel="loggingChannel" message-converters="jackson2http" 
                               reply-timeout="10000"  />
```

Below line in detailed logs after show correct conversion from **Object to JSON**-:

```
Writing [{"phoneNo":"1617xxxxxxx","orderNmb":"2073xxxxx"}] as "application/json"
```

**Detailed logs**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
    org.springframework.integration.router.PayloadTypeRouter : (inner bean)#53c8bb96 received message: GenericMessage [payload=com.xxxx.json.entity.Obj@235a8276, headers={timestamp=1430802166667, id=f3c3577d-bf44-b54d-b5e6-6b3f88a5746b, content-Type=application/json, accept=application/json, authorization=someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome}]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ObjHttpObjToJsonChannel'
    org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler : org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=com.xxxx.json.entity.Obj@235a8276, headers={timestamp=1430802166667, id=f3c3577d-bf44-b54d-b5e6-6b3f88a5746b, content-Type=application/json, accept=application/json, authorization=someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome}]
    org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler : org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#2 received message: GenericMessage [payload={"phoneNo":"16173313826","orderNmb":"2070000383","firstName":"A"}, headers={timestamp=1430802166759, id=7584cee1-8392-c71c-75f4-026d423e26c2, json__TypeId__=class com.xxxx.json.entity.Obj, content-Type=application/json, accept=application/json, authorization=someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome, contentType=application/json}]
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : outboundHeaderNames=[Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept-Ranges, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Type, Cookie, Date, Expect, From, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Max-Forwards, Pragma, Proxy-Authorization, Range, Referer, TE, Upgrade, User-Agent, Via, Warning]
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[timestamp] WILL NOT be mapped
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[json__typeid__] WILL NOT be mapped
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[content-type] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=content-type
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : setting headerName=[content-Type], value=application/json
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[accept] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=accept
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : setting headerName=[accept], value=application/json
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[authorization] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=authorization
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : setting headerName=[authorization], value=someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : headerName=[contenttype] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=contenttype
    org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper : setting headerName=[contentType], value=application/json
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate : Created POST request for "http://www.someurl.com/something"
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate : Writing [{"phoneNo":"1617xxxxxxx","orderNmb":"2073xxxxx"}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@774490f3]
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate : POST request for "http://www.someurl.com/something" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.xxxx.page.controller.ObjController.sendObj(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws com.xxxx.utils.exception.SomePageException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.xxxx.page.controller.ObjController.sendObj(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws com.xxxx.utils.exception.SomePageException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.xxxx.page.controller.ObjController.sendObj(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws com.xxxx.utils.exception.SomePageException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.xxxx.page.controller.ObjController.sendObj(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws com.xxxx.utils.exception.SomePageException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver : Resolving to view 'error' for exception of type [org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException], based on exception mapping [java.lang.Exception]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver : Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exception=org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request}
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:546)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:517)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:462)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:422)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:164)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:125)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:302)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:417)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:374)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.sendObj(Unknown Source)
        at com.xxxx.page.controller.ObjController.sendObj(ObjController.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The Wireshark packet trace difference from what I observed is as below.

Working request trace from Postman Rest Client!

```
 No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  16733 484.996811000  10.1.XX.XXX           192.XX.XX.XXX         HTTP     1126   POST /chapi/v1/some HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1  (application/json)

Frame 16733: 1126 bytes on wire (9008 bits), 1126 bytes captured (9008 bits) on interface 1
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_2d:4e:49 (a0:2b:xx:xx:xx:49), Dst: Cisco_ff:fc:04 (00:08:xx:xx:fx:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.1.XX.XXX (10.1.XX.XXX), Dst: 192.XX.XX.XXX (192.XX.XX.XXX)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 60374 (60374), Dst Port: 80 (80), Seq: 2921, Ack: 1, Len: 1072
[3 Reassembled TCP Segments (3992 bytes): #16728(1460), #16729(1460), #16733(1072)]
    [Frame: 16728, payload: 0-1459 (1460 bytes)]
    [Frame: 16729, payload: 1460-2919 (1460 bytes)]
    [Frame: 16733, payload: 2920-3991 (1072 bytes)]
    [Segment count: 3]
    [Reassembled TCP length: 3992]
    [Reassembled TCP Data: 504f5354202f6d6f62696c6553657276696365732f737470...]
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /chapi/v1/some HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Host: something.com\r\n
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    Content-Length: 94\r\n
    Accept: application/json\r\n
    Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
    Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36\r\n
    Authorization: someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome\r\n
    Content-Type: application/json\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n
     [truncated]Cookie: _br_mzv=eyIxIjozLCIyIjox
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://www.something.com//chapi/v1/some ]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 16746]
JavaScript Object Notation: application/json
    Object
        Member Key: "phone"
            String value: 1617xxxXXXX
        Member Key: "orderNumber"
            String value: 12xxXXXXX
        Member Key: "application"
            String value: orderPickup
```

Request not working from Application as per above code configuration !

```
   No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      89769 2664.453624000 10.1.XX.XXX           192.XX.XX.XXX         HTTP     491    POST /chapi/v1/some HTTP/1.1  (application/json)

    Frame 89769: 491 bytes on wire (3928 bits), 491 bytes captured (3928 bits) on interface 1
    Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_xx:xx:49 (a0:2b:xx:xx:xx:49), Dst: Cisco_ff:fc:04 (00:08:xx:xx:fx:04)
    Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.1.XX.XXX (10.1.XX.XXX), Dst: 192.XX.XX.XXX (192.XX.XX.XXX)
    Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 60618 (60618), Dst Port: 80 (80), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 437
    Hypertext Transfer Protocol
        POST /chapi/v1/some HTTP/1.1\r\n
        Accept: application/json\r\n
        authorization: someWE6JHRhcGwzc0MwZDNCcsome\r\n
        Content-Type: application/json\r\n
        Content-Length: 91\r\n
        Host: something.com\r\n
        Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
        User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)\r\n
        Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n
        \r\n
        [Full request URI: http://www.something.com/chapi/v1/some]
        [HTTP request 1/1]
        [Response in frame: 89778]
    JavaScript Object Notation: application/json
    Line-based text data: application/json
        "{\"phoneNo\":\"1617xxxXXXX\",\"orderNmb\":\"207xxXXXX\",\"application\":\"orderPickup\"}"
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like this are too general; you need to provide more details.

This requires you to use some basic debugging skills.

**Step 1:** Look at the server side logs to see what it is complaining about.

If that doesn't yield the solution,

**Step 2:** Compare a network monitor trace of the "good" and "bad" requests and figure out what's different between them. If you see what's different and can't figure out how to configure the gateway to replicate the "good" request then come back here with that **specific** question.

You can get a network trace with Wireshark or the eclipse TCP/IP Monitor, etc.

**EDIT:**

As you can see from the trace, you are doing two JSON conversions.

Remove the `object-to-json-transformer` and just let the outbound gateway do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, I am updating the question with the observation of difference in Wireshark responses in a min.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for help, keeping either of them works perfect!